# Parsing an input markup

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, iterator

I am trying to parse a markup of the form-

```
!TAG1 VAL1=0.88 VALARRAY=0. 0. 0.8 !TAG2 VAL2=0.998 !END !END'
```

As far as markup goes, I know that it is a rather bad way of representing real vectors without quotes. But it is parsed in an older code I am working on and I would not want to change the "standard" input format.
I have already implemented a do while loop for parsing this - where the program goes through the string word for word (word=not containing spaces) and two counters - one that sticks to the word position that that has the last `=` and the second seeks out the next word containing an `=`. Any ideas for a nice pythonic iterator that can chew out each `VAR=VALUE` pair?

EDIT1:Here is my solution for this, although I got to it after quite a few iterations. Hence it is not very readable!

```
s1='!TAG1 VAL1=0.88 VALARRAY=0. 0. 0.8 !TAG1 VAL2=0.998 !END !END'
list=[]
word=''
for s in s1.split():
    if (s[0]=='!'):
        if word : list.append(word)
        list.append(s) 
        word=''
    else :
        if '=' in s:
            if word : list.append(word)
            word=s
        else:
            word=(word+" "+s).strip()
if word: list.append(word)

print s1
print list
```

The output is-

```
!TAG1 VAL1=0.88 VALARRAY=0. 0. 0.8 !TAG1 VAL2=0.998 !END !END
['!TAG1', 'VAL1=0.88', 'VALARRAY=0. 0. 0.8', '!TAG1', 'VAL2=0.998', '!END', '!END']
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Do you want to ignore words preceded by `!`? In other words, can you give example matches from your given example.

Comment: It does, give me a few minutes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explanation:**

```
 (?# capture valueless keys)
 !          (?# match !)
 (          (?# start capturing group)
  \S+       (?# match non-whitespace characters)
 )          (?# end capturing group)
|           (?# OR)
 (?# capture key/value pairs)
 (          (?# start capturing group)
  \S+?      (?# lazily match non-whitespace)
 )          (?# end capturing group)
 =          (?# match literal =)
 (          (?# start capturing group)
  [^=]+?    (?# lazily match anything but =)
 )          (?# end capturing group)
 (?# values have a loose definition, so we need to lookahead for a delimiter)
 (?=        (?# start lookahead)
  \s*       (?# match optional whitespace)
  (?:       (?# start non-capturing group)
    \S+?=   (?# match another key)
   |        (?# OR)
    !\S+    (?# match another key w/o value)
   |        (?# OR)
    $       (?# match end of the string)
  )         (?# end non-capturing group)
 )          (?# end lookahead)
```

[Regex101](http://regex101.com/r/fJ6tJ7)

---

**Visualization:**

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/iFEUBWEyEmOgIjq5)

---

**Notes:**

Your valueless keys (`!TAG`) will be in the first capture group, and the key/value pairs (`VAL1=0.88`) will be in the second/third capture groups, respectively.  The valueless keys are easy, just match a `!` and then capture any non-whitespace characters (`\S = [^\r\n\t\f ]`). Key/value pairs are more difficult, we start by non-whitespace characters, followed by `=`, followed by any non-`=` (which OP mentioned was okay).  However, we need a way to stop the values from continuing to the end of the string.  So we make this a lazy match, and then lookahead for whitespace followed by: another key/value, another valueless key, or the end of the string.

---

Let's not forget the minified version ;)

```
!(\S+)|(\S+?)=([^=]+?)(?=\s*(?:\S+?=|!\S+|$))
```

Comment: Although I was looking for a more readable solution, the sheer illegibility of your solution blew me away :) !  
And sure enough this does work as I intended to, using some re.iterator object. Thanks!

Comment: Haha, I tried to explain it as best as I could.  Without strong delimiters (like spaces, or values enclosed in double quotes), it gets complicated to parse.  And the `!TAG1` keys just added another level of difficulty.  Let me know if anything needs further explanation.